# time delayed redirect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a website which slides to a "section" called blog in my HTML. I want the user to simply see the page for a brief second or 2 then redirect to my blog engine.

Please suggest a time delayed redirect?

If i can redirect with a time delayed based on the click of the blog li:

```
<li data-target="blog" data-target-activation="click" class="tile icon_add_favourite">
          <div>
            <h2>Blog</h2><h3>13</h3>
                <script type="text/JavaScript">
                &lt;!--
                    setTimeout("location.href = 'http://www.mysite.co.uk/blog';", 1500);
                --&gt;
                </script>
          </div>
        </li>
```

**UPDATE:** This is sooo strange when the HTML5 slides to the section block the page is still rendering with all the code and therefore the JS should be fired by the click event then run the redirect based on the timer.

The solutions work in JS as the alert boxes pop up. Wonder why they dont work in my page?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

**Edit:**

> The problem i face is that HTML5 is all on one index page. So i need
>   the timer to start on click of the blog link.

Try calling the setTimeout inside a click handler on the blog link,

```
$('#blogLink').click (function (e) {
   e.preventDefault(); //will stop the link href to call the blog page

   setTimeout(function () {
       window.location.href = "blog.html"; //will redirect to your blog page (an ex: blog.html)
    }, 2000); //will call the function after 2 secs.

});
```

---

Try using `setTimeout` function like below,

```
setTimeout(function () {
   window.location.href = "blog.html"; //will redirect to your blog page (an ex: blog.html)
}, 2000); //will call the function after 2 secs.
```

Comment: The problem i face is that HTML5 is all on one index page. So i need the timer to start on click of the blog link.

Comment: @sp-1986 see my updated answer which will call the setTimeout function after the blog link is clicked and will call the blog page after 2 seconds.

Comment: check the edit out... its not technically a link in HTML5 is it?

Comment: @sp-1986 Just add `blogLink` as an ID to the `li`. Also change the `...href="blog.html"` to `...href="http://www.mysite.co.uk/blog"`

Answer (score 69):

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2; url=http://example.com/" />
```

Here `2` is delay in seconds.

Comment: +1 for the solution that doesn't even require javascript to be enabled.

Comment: The problem i face is that HTML5 is all on one index page. So i need the timer to start on click of the blog link.

Comment: Woah, I had no idea this was possible with native HTML. Nice!

Comment: Just want to point out that W3C has deprecated the use of meta-refresh: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh The solution in the accepted answer using JS should be used instead.

Answer (score 18):

```
 <script type="text/JavaScript">
      setTimeout("location.href = 'http://www.your_site.com';",1500);
 </script>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can easily create timed redirections with JavaScript. But I suggest you to use *location.replace('url')* instead of *location.href*. It prevents to browser to push the site into the history. I found [this JavaScript redirect](http://insider.zone/tools/client-side-url-redirect-generator/) tool. I think you could use this.

Example code (with 5 secs delay):

```
<!-- Pleace this snippet right after opening the head tag to make it work properly -->

<!-- This code is licensed under GNU GPL v3 -->
<!-- You are allowed to freely copy, distribute and use this code, but removing author credit is strictly prohibited -->
<!-- Generated by http://insider.zone/tools/client-side-url-redirect-generator/ -->

<!-- REDIRECTING STARTS -->
<link rel="canonical" href="https://yourdomain.com/"/>
<noscript>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL=https://yourdomain.com/">
</noscript>
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script type="text/javascript">var IE_fix=true;</script><![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = "https://yourdomain.com/";
    var delay = "5000";
    window.onload = function ()
    {
        setTimeout(GoToURL, delay);
    }
    function GoToURL()
    {
        if(typeof IE_fix != "undefined") // IE8 and lower fix to pass the http referer
        {
            var referLink = document.createElement("a");
            referLink.href = url;
            document.body.appendChild(referLink);
            referLink.click();
        }
        else { window.location.replace(url); } // All other browsers
    }
</script>
<!-- Credit goes to http://insider.zone/ -->
<!-- REDIRECTING ENDS -->
```

Comment: Hmm I get XDomainRequest not found :/

Comment: @shaneonabike my bad, I just updated to make it work.

Answer (score 4):

Include this code somewhere when you slide to your 'section' called blog.

```
$("#myLink").click(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.navigate("the url of the page you want to navigate back to");
    }, 2000);
});
```

Where `myLink` is the id of your href.

Comment: The problem i face is that HTML5 is all on one index page. So i need the timer to start on click of the blog link.

Comment: Ah, okay. Editing to reflect. Edit: @sp-1986, try my newly edited answer on for size.

Comment: Elliot my friend, i have added an edit. I dont know if the click event will work for a LI ?

Comment: It'll work fine, provided your LI has the id 'myLink'. You can set the ID to whatever you want; just make sure you change the ID in the above code as well.

Comment: I'm pretty sure jsfiddle blocks attempts to redirect the page.  Try testing with a simple `alert` first.  Also, it looks like you have Mootools selected instead of jQuery?

Comment: works in jsfiddle with an alert, but doesnt work in my HTML 5 page.

Comment: The issue must lie elsewhere, then.

Comment: sp-1986: You should make a new question, as this one has already received a number of answers, one of which has been accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You can include this directly in your buttun. It works very well. I hope it'll be useful for you.
onclick="setTimeout('location.href = `../../dashboard.xhtml`;', 7000);"

Comment: \````../../dashboard.xhtml`\```    Don't forget to put the symbol in the beginning at the end