# MVC4 validation Error Display

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

I have a MVC 4 view (Razor) that accepts a code sent to a user. They get a number tries to enter it correctly. Each try that is entered wrong they get a validation error "Confirmation Number Incorrect - Please Re-enter" except on the last one, where they exceeded they get a validation error "Too Many Attempts - New Confirmation Number Has Been Sent" then they are immediately redirected to the home page. The problem is there is no delay so the message is never seen.

I really don't want to create another view to post the message with a button to redirect. Is there any way to delay some period of time then redirect the page? Any ideas?

Comment: how are you displaying last message, with ajax ?

Comment: Just put your last message into sessions, and check that after you redirected into home page, and display it in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are displaying message via ajax you can use this javascript function to redirect with delay:

```
// display message and ..
setTimeout(function () {
   window.location.href = @Url.Action("Index","Home")
}, 2000)
```

It will redirect user after two seconds.Also you can take a look to this question: [time delayed redirect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877263/time-delayed-redirect)