# Redirect to home page if cart is empty

Tags: magento, redirect, shopping-cart

I want to redirect user to home page if shopping cart is empty, is this possible to do from admin panel, if yes please guide, otherwise I have to redirect by controller overloading.

Comment: @amitBera what do you mean by RS Blog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do this from the admin, but you could try

1. In `app/design/frontend/default/your-theme/template/checkout/cart/noItems.phtml` add (this may not be the best solution but does work)

   ```
    <?php Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect($this->getContinueShoppingUrl()); ?>
   ```
2. Create an observer (try `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_delete`) that check if your cart is empty then redirect see to the home page 
   ([for redirecting from observer see](http://www.antoinekociuba.com/2012/12/magento-redirect-home-to-base-url/))
3. Using javascript and timer so that the user will see that there cart is empty before redirecting to home page (see [time delayed redirect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877263/time-delayed-redirect)) Add code below to `noItems.phtml` see solution #1

   ```
   <script>
    setTimeout(function () {
      window.location.href = "<?php echo $this->getContinueShoppingUrl() ?>"; //will redirect  to your blog page (an ex: blog.html)
    }, 2000); //will call the function after 2 secs.
   </script>
   ```

Comment: First solution doesn't work, also I don't think its good to redirect from phtml file. observer is last option I think. Thank you for reply

Comment: yes but its hack, I wanted to see if there is any solution provided by magento. Thanks for reply

Comment: None of the above are 'hack', they are customization (assuming that you didn't make any changes to magento core files)

Comment: it will first load empty cart page and then redirect user to home page. Time wastage of user. Observer is the right solution, redirect as soon as cart has no items with out double redirection.

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your `functions.php`

```
function cart_empty_redirect_to_shop() {
    global $woocommerce;

    if ( is_page('cart') and !sizeof($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents) ) {
        wp_redirect( get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'shop' ) ) ); exit;
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'cart_empty_redirect_to_shop' );
```

The above will redirect an empty cart to the shop page.

Comment: Question was about Magento, not Wordpress