# How do I print something in Tomcat Servlet, sleep for 3 seconds and then forwarding to another servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, forward

This is a project for my study.

I have a JSP with checkboxes which I will store into an Array in the Result.class (Result servlet) after clicking Submit on the JSP page. But before that, I have a PageProcessing (to show some processing text before showing the result of the Array) that will be shown before the Result servlet.

I want to let the PageProcessing servlet show some text and then sleep for 3 seconds before forwarding to the next servlet. The only thing that doesn't work is that it doesn't show the out.println(""); text before sleeping.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

                try {
                    out.println("<h1>Processing..."
                            + "<br>"
                            + "<h2>Please wait.</h2>");             
                } finally {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(3000);

                        request.getRequestDispatcher("Result").forward(request, response);

                        out.close();

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {                      
                        e.printStackTrace();                        
                    }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Most likely your buffer is not full enough to flush before sleep is called - more importantly though, you should NEVER call sleep inside a servlet.

Comment: Exactly. You should write out some Javascript that causes the *browser* to sleep.

Comment: What do you recommend me to do then? All I want is just a few seconds delay after the out.println text and then forwarding to the next Servlet.

Comment: So you guys recommend me not to write down a sleep within a servlet?

Comment: It makes absolutely no sense to have your server side code sleep (thus using up a connection). You're much better off sending HTML back to the client which contains a javascript onload function, which will wait for 3 seconds, then request your alternative Servlet. Lots of this is already implemented in jQuery.

Comment: I'm assuming the sleep() is to simulate a long running operation during the execution of which you would show some kind of processing indicator in the browser. The implementation you have suggested is *NOT* going to work. You need something like suggested by @Dave

Comment: Ah thank you Dave. I will have a try with that.

Comment: If you were to send some text to the client, then the response would be committed and you could not forward the request.

Answer (score 2):

Return a complete page to the user and close the connection. This will display a nice status page to the client. Then, let the client re-connect (META REFRESH, jQuery, raw AJAX, timed Javascript window.location='...', etc.) and fetch the follow-up resource.

**EDIT 2020-09-08**

Examples:

- [meta refresh](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_http_equiv.asp)
- [jQuery refresh](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/jquery-redirect-to-another-page-after-5-seconds-exampleexample.html)
- [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877263/time-delayed-redirect) (also includes other strategies)

Comment: Can you give an example? @Christopher Schultz