# sweetalert before php redirect

Tags: php, redirect, sweetalert

I'm trying to set sweetalert2 before automatic redirect on login if the user is not logged, but it appear just a second and redirect start immediately, how can i set to wait user click?

my actual code:

```
<?php
session_start();
if ($_SESSION[logged] != 'yes') { 
echo '
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/sweetalert2.css">
<script src="javascripts/custom/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    swal("Oops...", "Not logged!", "error");
    document.location.href="/login.html"
});
</script>';
exit; 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could add a timer, like this one, this waits 5 seconds and then use the redirect

```
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    alert("Oops...Not logged! error");
    var millisecondsToWait = 5000;
    setTimeout(function() {
       document.location.href="/login.html"
    }, millisecondsToWait);

  });
```

instead of alert just use swal.

Answer (score 0):

Sweet alert has callback function:

```
swal({
    //options
}, function(isConfirm) {
     document.location.href="/login.html"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

what you need is delay to redirection line

```
   setTimeout(function () {
       window.location.href = "/login.html"; //will redirect to your page after 2000 ms
    }, 2000);
```

Source:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9877274/3615630