# TimerTick event is not firing when hooked inside !IsPostBack

Tags: c#, asp.net, timeout, ispostback

New to asp.net.

My motive is,

"User has to be taken to some page after a predefined set of the time interval. 
Session should not be used."

So, I thought to use Timer and inside the timer tick event, I can do a Server.Redirect. This timer is inside the user control page, which is common across all pages.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            redirectTimer.Interval = 20000;
            redirectTimer.Tick += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(redirectTimer_Tick);                
        }
    }

    void redirectTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Server.Transfer("~/SomePageGoesHere.aspx");
    }
```

Case 2:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            redirectTimer.Interval = 20000;
            redirectTimer.Tick += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(redirectTimer_Tick);                            
    }

    void redirectTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Server.Transfer("~/SomePageGoesHere.aspx");
    }
```

But in this case, it worked.

My question is,

1. Whether "!IsPostBack" is having something to do with timer? (Case 1 and 2).
2. Is there any better approach available other than this timer, session or cookies. etc?

Could someone share some input here?

Comment: Web application does not work the same as windows application work. The C# code of web application is executed only when you submit a page to the server. So the Timer.Tick event is not going to be executed in background. You need to implement something at the client side using Javascript and Jquery to perform automatic redirection after some interval so. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877263/time-delayed-redirect

Comment: Possible duplicate of [time delayed redirect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877263/time-delayed-redirect)

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya: Thx for the reply. "The C# code of web application is executed only when you submit a page to the server" - Ah, the page_load function is called before sending the response to the client right? And also I tried for breakpoint inside TimerTick in case 2, and it was hitting. Is it not enough? Am I misunderstanding something? Could u pls clarify more. Thx.

Comment: Code of `Page_Load` is executed whenever you submit the page. But the code of `redirectTimer_Tick` will not be executed in background when the page displayed on the browser. I suggest to learn about how the request processing works in web application.