# Download file and display "thank you" msg on same page PHP

Tags: php, csv, header

I am using PHP and apache for my program. Where `index.php` is an input HTML form that accepts CSV file and some text data and does some validations. In case of proper inputs, calls `UpdateData.php`, which does some updations with an input file (using DB data), and after updating, the file gets downloaded using headers.

All I want is to display the Thankyou message after a successful download. I tried to use flags and sessions, but after setting headers every set value gets vanished. So any kinda help is appreciated!

Here's my code!

index.php

```
<?php

function validate ( $csv_index ) {
$error = "";
// code for CSV file validation check
// returns error content if any error
// else returns false
}

$error = "";
$success = "";

if ( !empty ($_POST['submit']) )
{     
      //POST data fetch
      $tmp_file_name = $_FILES['file']['name']; 
      $csv_index = $_POST['csv_index'];

      // call validate
      $error = validate ( $csv_index );

      if ($error == false) {
        include 'updateData.php';
      }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>

  <form  id="form" action="index.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    INPUT FILE<input type="file" name="file" id="file" required>
    CSV ROW No<input type="text" id="csv_index" name="csv_index" required>
    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" name="submit">
  </form>

<p style="text-align:center;"><b><?php if ( $error !== "" ) echo ( "Error occured"); ?></b></p>
<p id="error" style="color:red;text-align:center;"><b><?php echo ( "$error" ); ?></b></p>

<p style="text-align:center;">
<?php      
      if ( !empty($_GET["successflag"]) ){
      if ($_GET["successflag"] == 1 ) {
        echo ( "Thank you! File downloaded"); 
      }}
    ?>
</p>
    
</body>
</html>
```

updateData.php

```
<?php

// 
include_once('dbConfig.php'); 

// code to update file
// $updatedFileHandler is file pointer/handler of Updated file
// below code simply downloads a file               

fseek( $updatedFileHandler, 0 ); 
header( 'Content-Type: csv; charset=utf-8' ); 
header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $NewFileName . '";'); 
fpassthru( $updatedFileHandler );
fclose( $updatedFileHandler );

?>
```

After `fclose()` I tried to use `header("location: index.php?successflag=1");` but it simply stays on same page, displays Success msg without downloading file.
Please suggest if there could be any way to do it!

Comment: On updateData.php page, I think it is force download. You can use `readfile()` instead. [See example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7263943/128761). Make sure that this download works before continue on success message.

Comment: About success message after download. Use `header()` after send out file download is not recommended because it will be error _header already sent_. The download page should donate for download function only. To display success you should use JavaScript to detect link clicked and [delay redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877263/time-delayed-redirect/16541769).

Comment: @veeThank you for kind advice! IG Javascript supposes to execute before PHP, plus I have function called `validate()` . In case of error, file shouldn't be downloaded neither success msg will displayed. As per your advise, if I use JS onClick (submit button), it should work after `if ($error == false) ` and before  `include 'updateData.php';` in `index.php` . Hence not able to execute JS in between PHP :(